# Russian term for "verbal inspiration"

Tags: перевод

What is the russian term for "verbal inspiration".

It is the teaching, that God basically gave each an every word of the original text of the bible to its authors, which wrote them down.

For ukrainian I found `Богонатхнення` on Wikipedia, but I could not find a russian term. It seems `вербальное вдохновение` is not the correct translation.

Comment: maybe this will help: `we may draw inspiration from the words of ...` = `мы можем черпать вдохновение в словах ...`

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the theory of "verbal inspiration" in Russian Orthodoxy is usually referred as "Вербальная теория богодухновенности" or simply "Вербализм". Needless to say it's not considered as canonical one.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's *богодухновение* (*боговдохновение, богодухновенность, боговдохновенность*).

2 Timothy 3:16 (KJV):

> All scripture is given by inspiration of God, and is profitable for doctrine, for reproof, for correction, for instruction in righteousness:

in Russian Synodal Bible reads:

> Все Писание богодухновенно и полезно для научения, для обличения, для исправления, для наставления в праведности

, same verse in Elizabeth Bible (Church Slavonic):

> Всяко писанiе богодухновенно и полезно есть ко оученiю, ко ωбличенiю, ко исправленiю, къ наказанiю еже въ правдѣ.

**Update:**

Alexander Men's "Bible Dictionary" mentions [this](http://goo.gl/hifNgP):

> ВЕРБАЛИ́ЗМ (от лат. verbum — слово), теория, согласно к-рой Писание полностью было продиктовано Духом Святым и поэтому каждое его слово (и даже каждую его букву) как исходящее от Бога следует понимать в буквальном смысле как слово Бога.

Comment: Understood. As I understand there are different teachings of how the divine inspiration "works". That God is the source of inspiration all these teachings have in common. So my point is, that the "verbal inspiration" claims, that God inspired word by word of the original texts (in aramaic, hebrew and greek) and the authors basically just wrote down these words.

Comment: @Hogardson: well, I'm not very well versed in subtleties of Christian doctrines. All I did was translate the term you mentioned from Ukrainian to Russian and make sure it's mentioned in the Bible in a meaning close to what you are looking for. Here's an article from Alexander Men's "Bible Dictionary" (in Russian): http://goo.gl/jEr87L, which covers the subject in more detail.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Maybe it will yield something helpful on this topic.

Answer (score -1):

A possible candidate would be the verb

**воодушевить**, as in

*И воодушевил меня своими словами.*

Comment: I'm **not** the downvoter but my guess would be that you are downvoted because author actually looked for a very specific theological terminology.